# Handling mixed data-type columns in CSV while using the 64bit Microsoft Access Text Driver

Tags: csv, vbscript, asp-classic, odbc

I am a developer helping to maintain a fairly large online application written in Classic-ASP/VBScript running on Server 2008 r2 in IIS7 in 64bit mode.

One of the features requires the import of a CSV file by end users and as a result of moving this system into a 64bit environment we changed our code to use "Microsoft Access Text Drivers" from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255 since these work on 64bit applications.

This all worked fine however, recently we have encountered some issues with our imports where data in a column is being interpreted as numeric when it should be read as text. What this ultimately means is that in these columns plain text values are being returned as NULL.

Formatting the CSV better and ensuring that the strings are wrapped in double quotes does resolve the issue but given that this file is being supplied by end users who may not have the understanding/expertise to make these changes it is not really a viable solution in production.

Our preferred solution would be to have the text drivers treat these mixed content columns as text however I have been unable to come to a solution which achieves this.

---

I have considered/tried the following...

1. I have considered using a schema.ini file however for this specific import we can not know the column names/order before the CSV has been read as we offer the ability for end users to re-map their data into our expected columns when they don't match.
2. I have tried to use the IMEX=1 property to handle mixed data types however it does not seem to be having any affect. I have had  success with this in JET drivers however being a 64 bit system this is not an option. I am relativly confident the issue is not in the MaxScanRows since the first row of data contains a plain text value.

Below is an extract of our code which attempts to use IMEX to solve the issue.

```
    ' The following variables are defined earlier in the code 
    ' however I am showing them here for clarity
    environmentTextDriver = "Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)"
    folderName = "/_uploads/offline"
    fileName = import_xxx.csv ' Dynamic file name

    ' Open text database
    Set DBText = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    DBText.Provider = "MSDASQL"
    DBText.ConnectionString = "Driver={" & environmentTextDriver & "};Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";Dbq=" & Server.MapPath(folderName) & ";Extensions=csv;"
    ' I have also tried the following connection string
    ' DBText.ConnectionString = "Driver={" & environmentTextDriver & "};HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;Dbq=" & Server.MapPath(folderName) & ";Extensions=csv;"
    DBText.Open 

    ' Set query
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & fileName & ";"
    Set rs = DBText.Execute(strSQL)
    if not rs.EOF then
        arrResponse = rs.getRows()
        ' Debug, print out results for error column
        for i = 0 to uBound(arrResponse,2)
            response.write arrResponse(18, i) & "&"
        next
    end if
    rs.close : set rs = nothing

    ' Close database
    DBText.close : set DBText = nothing
```

I'm hoping I'm just doing something silly and not that the Microsoft Access Text Drives don't support it. Any assistance would be most appreciated.

Regards,

Nick

Comment: As the `schema.ini` file is a text file itself, you could try analysing the file using VB Script (Classic ASP) and then building the ini file based on your findings. [Edit: Though it will, obviously, depend on where the file is located].

Comment: Hmm, that is a possibility. The downside being that we would need to open the file twice, once to analyse it and then again to load in the data.

I'll certainly keep this on the cards as an option but if we can get the IMEX property to behave as I thought it was meant to it would save a lot of hassle.

Still a good suggestion, thanks for the idea!

Comment: are you sure MAXSCANROWS is not causing the issue? as said here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714864(v=vs.85).aspx "The data type is determined given the maximum number of kinds of data found". so even if the first row contains text data it will scan 24 more rows and then guess the datatype.

Comment: Hi ulluoink. I am fairly confident it isn't simply a max scan rows issue as I have tested on data sets where the first row contains a string.